# How to exit or break out from an else if

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've searched for a couple stackoverflow questions although couldn't find my answer.

I'm trying to break from an else if statement and was wondering if there was a more efficient way.

Heres a snippet:

```js
var argument = "something";

if(argument == 'not_this'){
  // this doesn't trigger
} else if(argument){
  // this triggers although if the functions in here doesn't match what I want, 
  // how do I make It skip to the else statement without adding another else
  // if statement? 
} else {
  // do something if both statements above fail
}
```

Is there something that I can do which exits from the `else if(argument)...` without adding another else statement? I've tried using `switch` and `case` although those don't seem to help.

Thanks.

Comment: Add the necessary predicates to the `else if ()` test?

Comment: So imagine you had a variable "processed" .. And if you'd dealt with it you could have a second if - `if (!processed)` to deal with the other cases.  All you need to do is set `processed=true;` when you have processed it.

Comment: Hi @Pointy - that can't work - his question is if in the code block of `if (argument)` the algorithm knows he needs to do alternate processing (the same as the original not covered cases)...

Comment: The answer by @Spectric is what my comment is saying (just in reverse logic).

Comment: Well then maybe split up the code into a couple of functions to be called. I don't know; this doesn't seem like a very complicated problem.

Comment: Working out logic like this outside the context of a program in any programming language, like with pencil and paper, is very often a good way of figuring out such logical problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a flag that is by default `true`, and whenever the argument is valid you set it to false.

Then, to know when to execute the 'else' block, you can just check whether the flag is true or not:

```js
var argument = "something";
let invalid = true

if (argument == 'not_this') {
  // this doesn't trigger
  invalid = false
} else if (argument) {
  if (typeof argument != 'string') {
    //valid
    invalid = false
  }
}

if (invalid) {
  console.log('invalid')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the code to avoid confusing states, move out the if 'has value' check.

```
if (argument) {
  if (argument === 'not_this') {
    // this doesn't trigger
  }
} else {
  // do something if both statements above fail
}
```

For equality, it is safer to use strict equal `===` instead of loose equal `==`

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for as I was trying to break out of the first statement if it fails and trigger the `else` statement. If the `if(argument==='not_this')` was moved into the `if(argument)` statement, nothing changes.

Answer (score -2):

You could try using `return;` to break out of the statement, as that would stop all other code from being read.

Comment: If you read my question, I'm asking for the `else` statement to trigger, and to break out of the `else if` statement.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).